# popup window on page load html5 responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

How to popup window on page load.I searched so many web sites,All are doing like Link click.But i wanted to show on page loading in html.is there any load method for showing pop up in j query.I referred this [Link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/)
.how to show on page loading.

Comment: Are you willing to use themes?

Comment: Try using bpopup this will help you http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Comment: wanted to show popup on page loading.

Comment: use jquery ui's dialogue api.

Comment: I do not have full awarness in jquery.I am new to jquery .Will you please show me some steps to go ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#modal').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',
            animationspeed: 600,
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
return false;
});
```

After long time thinking,I got answer from this [Link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/).Here i am posting the code regarding popup model in page loading.I hope this answer will help someone,Who ever wanted to do such kind of task.I have just removed a tag in the page and written jquery code in document.ready() function.Now popup will load in page loading only.